# Не могу понять почему не получается запустить вращение объекта вокруг другого[Unity]

Tags: unity3d

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы один корабль в игре летал вокруг оси другого.
Вот как я делаю это:

```
//выполняется до приближения объекта на нужное расстояние
angleBetween = Vector3.Angle(transform.position, Target.transform.position);

//после достижения нужного расстояния
angleBetween -= Time.deltaTime;
float x = Target.transform.position.x + 7.5f * Mathf.Cos(angleBetween);
float z = Target.transform.position.z + 7.5f * Mathf.Sin(angleBetween);
```

В итоге после того, как объект подлетает его положение на оси меняется на другое. Вроде посмотрев не увидел косяка в принимаемых значений и везде функции принимают/возвращают радианы.

Comment: Есть такая прикольная штука, RotateAround называется. Вот документация [доки](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html)

Answer (score 0):

Все намного проще

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    //обьект вокруг которого будем крутится
    public GameObject target;

    void Update()
    {
        // крутить со скоростью 20 градусов/сек.
        transform.RotateAround(target.transform.position, Vector3.up, 20 * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.RotateAround.html